# Why the terms "unit" and "irreducible"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology, definition, math-history

I'm trying to understand why in a ring we choose the names unit to an invertible element and irreducible element in this definition

> [image]

Maybe historical reasons?

For example, I suppose the second definition are named as prime elements because of the analogy to prime numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, *units* behave "like $1$", which explains their name.

Historically, prime nuumbers were rather defined as what is here called irreducible. And for integers, "irreducible" and "prime" coincide.
So for the general ring theory, where they do *not* coincide in general, one had to coin at least one new name. Since *irreducible* was established for (the ring of) polynomials and this well matches the notion that these elements cannot be (nontrivially) split into several factors, the name *prime* could be used for the other notion. (Alternatively, one would have had to coin a name for if-it-divides-a-product-it-divides-a-factor numbers)

Comment: why units behave like 1?

Comment: @user42912: 'unit' is not defined in your given definition. If you look at a definition, a unit divides a multiplicative identity, commutes with everything, and so has many similar properties to the multiplicative identity, which is often given the name '1' because it is so much like the integer 1.

Answer (score 3):

For example, in $\Bbb Z$, the units are $\pm 1$, and the primes and irreducibles coincide. Moreover, it has *unique factorization*, and unique here means 'up to a unit', e.g. $-10=(-1)\cdot 2\cdot 5$, but $-1$ doesn't count here, as it is only a unit. Among the Gaussian integers, $\Bbb Z[i]$ also $\pm i$ are units.

It is easy to see that if $u$ is a unit (invertible), then for any element $a$, the generated *ideals* $(a)$ and $(ua)$ coincide.